# How to select multiple email addresses from SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xslt, sql-server-2008-r2

In an XSL webpage, I'd like to select data for sending an email to multiple addresses taken from an SQL query.

The XSL code would be something like this:

[image]

where "@emails" would be taken from an SQL query (querying a table column).
I was thinking about creating a string: address + semicolon + space + address + semicolon + space... and so on until it runs out of email addresses.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do concatenation as:

```
select stuff((select '; ' + eMailColumn
from TableName
where SomeColumn = @conditionValue
    and eMailColumn is not NULL
for xml path('')), 1, 2, '')
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I've just added "as emails" at the end. Thanks!